# Problems to implement A* pathfinding Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pseudocode, path-finding

I have been trying to implement some pathfind system for weeks now and with no good results.

I am using Unity and the positions of each tilemap, I also have a list with all invalid coordinates.

In some positions my code makes the character walk an unnecessary long way to reach the goal and in some positions the game crashes (I think infinite loop).

I am trying to adapt the algorithm of A*, I will leave a picture of the pseudocode and I will also leave my code.

My goal is to return a valid path every time I execute the function. For now I am using a KeyValuePair list where the key is the node coordinate and the value is a float list, where index 0 represents the F in the pseudocode, 1 represents the G, 2 represents the H.

Sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing, I am using a translator. Sorry for my noob question.

[PseudoCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIOVY.png)

My Code:

```
    public Dictionary<Vector3,Vector3> ReturnNextPosition(Vector3 actualPosi, Vector3 finalPosi){
    

    List<KeyValuePair<Vector3,List<float>>> openVectors = new List<KeyValuePair<Vector3,List<float>>>();
    List<KeyValuePair<Vector3,List<float>>> closedVectors = new List<KeyValuePair<Vector3,List<float>>>();
    Dictionary<Vector3,Vector3> cameFrom = new Dictionary<Vector3, Vector3>();

    Vector3Int actualVector = new Vector3Int((int)actualPosi.x - 1, (int)actualPosi.y - 1, 0);
    Vector3Int finalVector = new Vector3Int((int)finalPosi.x - 1, (int)finalPosi.y - 1, 0);
    List<float> zeroList = new List<float>();
    zeroList.Add(ManhattanDistance(actualVector,finalVector)); zeroList.Add(0); zeroList.Add(0);
    var actualKV = new KeyValuePair<Vector3, List<float>>(actualVector,zeroList);
    openVectors.Add(actualKV);

    while(openVectors.Count > 0){

        KeyValuePair<Vector3, List<float>> qNode = openVectors[0];

        foreach(KeyValuePair<Vector3, List<float>> kvp in openVectors){
            if(kvp.Value[0] <= qNode.Value[0]){
                qNode = kvp;
            }
        }
        openVectors.Remove(qNode);
        closedVectors.Add(qNode);

        if(qNode.Key == finalPosi || qNode.Key == finalVector){
            return cameFrom;
        }

        List<Vector3> sucessors = new List<Vector3>();
        sucessors.Add(new Vector3(qNode.Key.x - 1, qNode.Key.y, qNode.Key.z));
        sucessors.Add(new Vector3(qNode.Key.x, qNode.Key.y - 1, qNode.Key.z));
        sucessors.Add(new Vector3(qNode.Key.x + 1, qNode.Key.y, qNode.Key.z));
        sucessors.Add(new Vector3(qNode.Key.x, qNode.Key.y + 1, qNode.Key.z));

        foreach(Vector3 v in sucessors){

            Vector3Int checkInvalid = new Vector3Int((int)v.x + 1,(int)v.y + 1,0);
            if(!tlmp.HasTile(new Vector3Int((int)v.x,(int)v.y,0))){
                continue;
            }
            if(invalidTile.Contains(v)){
                continue;
            }

            float gValue = qNode.Value[1] + Vector3.Distance(qNode.Key,v);
            float hValue = ManhattanDistance(v,finalVector);
            float fValue = gValue + hValue;

            foreach(KeyValuePair<Vector3, List<float>> kvp in openVectors){
                if(kvp.Key == v && gValue >= kvp.Value[1]){
                    continue;
                }
            }

            foreach(KeyValuePair<Vector3, List<float>> kvp in closedVectors){
                if(kvp.Key == v && gValue >= kvp.Value[1]){
                    continue;
                }
            }

            

            List<float> toAdd = new List<float>();
            toAdd.Add(fValue); toAdd.Add(gValue); toAdd.Add(hValue);
            var toAddKVP = new KeyValuePair<Vector3, List<float>>(v,toAdd);
            openVectors.Add(toAddKVP);
            try{
                cameFrom.Add(v,qNode.Key);
            }catch{}
            
        }

        
    }

    return cameFrom; 
    
}
```